# Facing error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks while using building app using npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradlew, mobile-development

[image]

Downloaded my repo from Github it is working fine on mac machine but I'm facing errors while building this project in my windows machine.
While building the project using npx react-native run-android I'm getting error i.e. -
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat tasks
'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.